# Create and split an array twice all inline in Powershell

Tags: arrays, powershell, split, powershell-3.0, pipeline

I have the following code which works but I am looking for a way to do this all inline without the need for creating the unnecessary variables `$myArray1` and `$myArray2`:

```
$line = "20190208 10:05:00,Source,Severity,deadlock victim=process0a123b4";
$myArray1 = $line.split(",");
$myArray2 = $myArray1[3].split("=");
$requiredValue = $myArray2[1];
```

So I have a string `$line` which I want to:

1. split by commas into an array.
2. take the fourth item `[3]` of the new array
3. split this by the equals sign into another array
4. take the second item of this array `[1]`
5. and store the string value in a variable.

I have tried using `Select -index` but I haven't been able to then pipe the result and split it again.

The following works:

```
$line.split(",") | Select -index 3
```

However, the following results in an error:

```
$line.split(",") | Select -index 3 | $_.split("=") | Select -index 1
```

Error message: *Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.*

Comment: `$line.Split(',=')[-1]`

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers thanks, I like that. It works well for this specific example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$line.Split(',')[3].Split('=')[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

Try below code:

```
$requiredValue = "20190208 10:05:00,Source,Severity,deadlock victim=process0a123b4" -split "," -split "=" | select -Last 1
```

Comment: Thanks Mudit, this works, I've upvoted but just slightly preferred Gert's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mudit already provided an answer, here's another about your particular case.

Piping to `foreach` and accessing 2nd element does the trick:

```
$line.split(",") | Select -index 3  | % {$_.split("=")[1]}
process0a123b4
```

That being said, aim for readability and ease of maintenance. There's nothing wrong with having intermediate variables. Memory is cheap nowadays, programmers' time is not. Optimization is due when it's needed and only then after careful profiling to see what's the actual bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe the second split to a foreach

```
$line.split(",") | Select -index 3 | foreach { $_.split("=") | Select -index 1 }
```